# Key not present on Coral Dev Board when configuring MDT with macOS host machine

Tags: macos-catalina, google-coral, mdt

I am currently following the [Coral Dev Board configuration guide](https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/get-started) using a MacOS machine running Catalina as my host machine. As per the instructions, for me to use the MDT command line tools on my specific host machine I must manually configure mdt. I used the following [guide](https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/mdt/#mdt-on-macos) step-by-step but end up with the following error when I try to connect to the board.

```
Waiting for a device...
Connecting to jumbo-goose at 192.168.0.78
Key not present on jumbo-goose -- pushing

It looks like you're trying to connect to a device that isn't connected
to your workstation via USB and doesn't have the SSH key this MDT generated.
To connect with `mdt shell` you will need to first connect to your device
ONLY via USB.

Cowardly refusing to attempt to push a key to a public machine.
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone would be able to assist me in debugging this issue. I have reflashed my device a few times so I am unsure where the issue is emerging.

Comment: Please check to meet those considerations in the error statement; connecting to USB and specifying the SSH key.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was using the USB connection (screen /dev/cu.usbmodem*) to pass through commands to the dev board. I followed the instructions as defined in the Coral guide by generating the ssh key and pasting the public key onto the dev board.

Answer (score 1):

On the Coral Dev Mini I had similar issues with generating ssh keys, especially when I switched from a Windows to Linux machine.  The easiest was (though not as secure) is to follow these steps and allows ssh with a password.  First you will need to connect with a USB cable.

https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-enable-ssh-password-authentication/

To edit use sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config

The key is to set: PasswordAuthentication yes

Answer (score 0):

Check the sha25sum of the key file transferred to the dev board is the same as on MacOS, mine didn't match i.e the cut and paste wasn't quite right. With key file transferred manually using a SD card it worked first time on mdt devices/mdt shell commands.